# adding css to express project and ejs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

im building a project in node/express/ejs and struggling to link the css to the ejs files and getting the css to show up in the browser. Ive created a public folder with a css folder inside that and the the main.css file inside. I've gone through tutorials to check how to do it but just not seeing how to fix this and get the cssto show up. Many thanks to anyone who can help :)

this is my app.js file with the app.use

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true}
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))


// Express body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Express session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles/main.css'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

this is the ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ab1675432.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>TBANK</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
          <div class="logo">
              <h1 class="logo-text"><span>T</span>BANK</h1>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="#">Savings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Borrowing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
      </header>
      <div class="main-body">
        <div class="home-heading">
          <h1 class="home-header">Bank with the future</h1> 
        </div>
        <!--<div class="container"><%- body %></div>-->

<div class="footer-container">
    <footer class="footer_area">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <span>T</span>BANK
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <ul class="list-style-company">
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <ul class="list-style-company">
            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Transparency</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How money works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How we protect you</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Business Accounts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="f_social_icon">
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to verify that your CSS is being served on the url you expect.
Go to your browser and check that your css is being served properly on url http://localhost:8080/css/main.css

If it is then this means you have a bad path to the css in your HTML. If its not being served properly then its either not configured properly or its at a different url.

My suspicion is that your url `css/main.css`(which is a url relative to the current page url) should be `/css/main.css` instead(which is relative to the root of your application).